# Запуск процессов из строки и перенаправление вывода

Tags: linux, bash

Написал функцию bash для запуска комплекса программ.

```
BIN_DIR=./bin
LOG_DIR=./log
function Run(){
   CFG="$2"
   echo $CFG
   if [ -z "$CFG" ]; then
      CFG=$(Config $1) #формируем дефолтную строку для конфига
   fi

   CMD="${BIN_DIR}/$1 $CFG >${LOG_DIR}/${1}.log 2>&1" #перенаправление
   echo $CMD #отладочный вывод что мы там запустили
   $CMD& #фоновый процесс
   sleep 1
}
```

Запуск

```
# 1 - имя приложения; "2" если конфиг передан строкой с пробелами
Run $1 "$2"
```

Программы валят весь лог в stderr, почему-то при запуске процесса через скрипт вывод не перенаправляется.

UPD
Пробовал перенаправлять только поток вывода

```
2>${LOG_DIR}/$1.log
```

Тоже не работает. Не понимаю что я не так делаю, почему валидная строка запуска в консоли работает, а в скрипте нет.

Comment: Можно перенаправлять оба потока в файл с помощью `&>`.

Comment: Вы хотите одновермено писать и в файл лога и в stdout ? если Вы хотите одновремено выводить в файл и stdout  , можно воспользоватся командой `tee`

Comment: @Yaroslav Хочу перенаправить весь вывод в файл. Пробовал и 2>./log/$1.log всеравно все валит в консоль

Comment: @JK_Action попробуйте сделать минимальный пример кода, воспроизводящий проблему — такой, чтобы его могли запустить у себя и поотлаживать читатели. Пока что все мои эксперименты заканчиваются успешно, не могу отловить ситуацию, в которой stderr не редиректится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перенаправления файловых дескрипторов — это синтаксические конструкции языка.

когда вы пытаетесь **интерпретировать переменную, содержащую строку**, в которой (строке) содержится **и** вызов какой-то программы (скрипта, функции), **и** данные синтаксические конструкции, они (конструкции) передаются вызываемой программе (скрипту, функции) ***простыми* аргументами**.

чтобы программа *bash* произвела полноценный синтаксический анализ интерпретируемой строки, содержащейся в переменной, надо воспользоваться встроенной командой `eval`:

```
eval $var
```

---

иллюстрирующий пример:

```
#!/bin/bash

f() {
  echo "количество аргументов = $#"
} 

c1="f abc"
c2="f abc 2>/dev/null"

$c1 # выведет "количество аргументов = 1"
$c2 # выведет "количество аргументов = 2"
eval $c2 # выведет "количество аргументов = 1"
```

Comment: Как насчёт `bash $var`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, аналогично случаю `$var`, только к тому же функции при этом нельзя будет вызывать.

Answer (score 0):

Я смог обойтись и без eval просто разнес формирование команды и сам вызов.

```
CMD="${BIN_DIR}/$1 $CFG"
echo $CMD
$CMD >${LOG_DIR}/${1}.log 2>&1&
#$CMD $>${LOG_DIR}/${1}.log &
```